# How to add external source files to Xcode without drag/drop method?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an external folder "external" with .h and .m files.

The "External" folder has added to my xcode project like below:
Project target > build Phase > Compile Source > + > Add Other > select the external folder > Checked Copy item if needed & select create folder reference.

However when compile its complain:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_HelloWorld", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CustomObject.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It work fine when i manual drag and drop the all files to project. However dislike the drag and drop methods. Is that an alternative way where xcode automatic compile with external source files without drag and drop.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if you've added your .m file twice somewhere

Comment: Checked the HelloWorld.m file never duplicate. Only one HelloWorld.m file in my current project

Answer (score 0):

i added folder i donot know whether that is correct process or not so first remove that folder reference from your project, we can do in other way here i am adding steps

- first inside your project editor, in left editor rightclick on one file that will show options like the following[image]
- click on **Add Files to "your project name"** then we have to choose folder and add.

Comment: That is the same shit with different steps

Answer (score -1):

With Xcode 5.1 and above, Apple has arm64 *(64 bit architecture - x86_64)* as part of **Standard architectures**. That means the projects using the default setting will be automatically build for arm64 also.

It seems that your project is not able to support 64-bit - you need to specifically set the architectures in build settings.

Project Targets >> Build Settings >> Architectures >> Standard architectures (armv7,armv7s)

[image]

Comment: I has removed the arm64 and set to only armv7 and armv7s in architecture as suggested but the error appear like previous

Comment: @kaneyip Have you properly linked your binary through `Link Binary with Libraries` of Build Phases?

Comment: If you have Build Settings for **Build Active Architecture Only** set to 'Yes' for Debug. Check **No** and try?

Comment: Also, I would check the architectures of the binary. Just do `lipo -info staticLibrary.a` on Terminal. So, x86_64 is missing? You see only among - armv7s armv7 arm64 i386.

Comment: Hi raurora, i has set 'No' for Debug in Build Active Architecture and retry to compile again. But the same error appear.

Comment: I'm confuse with the binary. my external folder only consist of .m and .h files. i need to add the external folder in Link Binary too? How to create the staticLibrary for my folder. Can Guide or with link?

Comment: [Static library](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) is .a and .h files which go together in your project. Looks like you have the source code (.h and .m). Just drag drop those to your project (remember to copy), and then create folders/groups. Nothing to link. Sorry my bad for not reading your first line of question. Drag/drop is best. Another possibility, is that you create a static library for your project (.a and .h) - this won't expose your implementation (.m) to others.

Comment: Raurora thanks for the suggestion. I wish there is a auto way to link and compile with external source (.m and .h files)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61960/discussion-between-raurora-and-kaneyip).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61963/discussion-between-raurora-and-kaneyip).